# Two-way data bound input field initially duplicates values when populating input field

Tags: angular, loops, data-binding, ngfor, 2-way-object-databinding

I am try to give the user the ability to rename a field and have the data populate across the whole app. I have this code:

```
<label>Constraint titles: </label>
<li *ngFor="let slider of twodsliders">
  <input [(ngModel)]="slider.name" name="consname" type="text" size="30" placeholder="Max Frogs"><br>
</li>
```

With this mock data:

```
const TWODSLIDERS: TwoDSlider[] = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Unknowability Bounderies', max_value: 89, min_value: 22 },
  { id: 2, name: 'Acceptable Throwing Distance', max_value: 67, min_value: 11 }
];
```

And this in the app component:

```
twodsliders = TWODSLIDERS;
```

While the data is bound to the correct values, so changing the first input value changes the value on the first model, and changing the value in the second changes the second, etc, there is the problem when the data is first populated. That is, the input boxes both initially contain the value "Acceptable Throwing Distance". What going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Answered my question while I was posting it but posted anyway for informational purposes. The solution is to add `name="{{slider.name}}"` to the input element. It then populates with the correct version straight away.

However, this caused additional unexpected behaviour (deleting all data in the input field caused an error), so instead I removed the name field entirely, and instead added `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"`. App now appears to be working as expected.